On button click font is getting bigger
The font's on Some of my webpages are behaving wierdly. When I click the button to reveal the text, the text above it is becoming bigger. Is there any fix for this? Especially, this is happening on chrome on mobile.
https://www.campusgate.in/2011/11/permutations.html?m=1


Please post related HTML and CSS codes.

It would help if you showed us some code that pertains to the page. There could be 1000 reasons why this would happen but without seeing your code, it's impossible for anyone to identify the problem.

@Raptor Here you go
https://github.com/srk7774/cg/blob/master/blogger_17.4.24

The issue could be because of the fonts. Your fonts takes time to load, and this causes the text to flicker for some time. Here I am adding the tests I performed on Slow 3g - Disable Cache  for your website.
Texts before the fonts are loaded.

Texts after the fonts are loaded. Also time taken on slow 3g to download the fonts.

